# Mysql function or procedure to check grants

Tags: mysql, privilege

An user should only execute functions and procedures. I grant `EXECUTE` to this user and revoke other privileges from the same user for security reasons.

How to check if this user has only the `EXECUTE` privilege for a stored function?

Comment: Please refer this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html

Comment: I want to check grant in stored function.

CREATE FUNCTION `get_max_price`() RETURNS int(11) unsigned
begin
  declare l int(11) unsigned;
  if "check user has just execute grant" then
    select  max(price)+1 into l from cars;
    return l;
  end if;
  return 0;
end;


I can call show grants. But how to check output in stored function?

Comment: You can define an exception using declare handler.. if user didn't have the privileges for certain operation, it will throws error which will be handled by the defined exception handler. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-handler.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR '<user>'@'<host>'
```

shows the grants for user. You can check user's grants.

```
SELECT * FROM  mysql.procs_priv WHERE Proc_priv='Execute' AND Routine_type='PROCEDURE' AND Routine_name='<routine_name>' AND User='<user>' Db='<db_name>' AND Host='<host>';
```

Db and Host may not be necessary

Comment: I don't want to get grants. I want to check grant in stored function.

Comment: Ok. I now checkin it. What privilege I need to perform 'SELECT * FROM information_schema.schema_privileges'? Is it just 'USAGE'?